# Finding the probability of a random variable (with a normal distribution) being less than or equal to a number using a Z table

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was watching this [video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/random-variables-stats-library/combine-random-variables/a/combining-normal-random-variables) from Khan Academy and the question was to find the probability of a random variable (with a normal distribution) being less than a certain number. The instructor finds the answer by using a Z table. My question is since he found the probability of a random variable being less than a number, how would I find the probability of a random variable being less than or equal to a number?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the difference between $\mathcal{P}(X < c)$ and $\mathcal{P}(X \leq c)$?  ... where $X$ is a random standard normally distributed variable and $c$ is some constant

Comment: @EricTowers Yes sir! how would I go about also finding that using a z table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the normal distribution is a continuous distribution, \begin{align*}
\mathcal{P}(X \leq c) &= \mathcal{P}((X < c) \cup (X = c))  \\
&= \mathcal{P}(X < c) + \mathcal{P}(X = c) - \mathcal{P}((X < c) \cap (X = c))  \\
&= \mathcal{P}(X < c) + 0 - 0  \\
&= \mathcal{P}(X < c) \text{.}
\end{align*}
The first zero, $\mathcal{P}(X = c) = 0$, is because the normal distribution is a continuous distribution : probabilities are given by integrals of its probability density function, but we are asking for the integral $\int_c^c \dots = 0$ which is zero because the endpoints of integration are the same.  The second zero, $\mathcal{P}((X < c) \cap (X = c)) = 0$, is zero because there are no realizations of $X$ that are simultaneously less than $c$ and equal to $c$.

So, the two probabilities you ask about are the same.  Use the same procedure for both.